# How to disable public key permission check on Git?

Tags: git, ssh

I'm using SSH key pair to connect on my Git repository.

This keys are stored on an external crypted volume. It's cool and safe, but it not support permission management well. My keys are see with 644 permission and git send to me the too open error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '***' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
key_load_private_type: bad permissions
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Is there a way to disable this permission check and how ?

Comment: Could you set umask/filemask/dirmask when you mount the volume?

Comment: What, specifically, makes you think exposing a private key to any-and-every-bit-of-code you run under your userid is "safe"?

Comment: Why, exactly, do you not just want to fix the root cause of the problem by changing the permissions on your ssh files/directories?

Comment: `chmod 400 <key>` and redo the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the volume and the OS.
But first:

> Is there a way to disable this permission check and how ?

No, there is not.

You can see in "[Bypass ssh key file permission check](https://serverfault.com/a/81756/783)" an example of mounting an encrypted volume ([TrueCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt) at the time) on OSX through `/etc/fstab` (in 2009).
Now (2017), [`/etc/fstab` seems to be still around](https://superuser.com/a/336474/141) and adding the right options (see [wiki.archlinux.org/fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab)) should allow to see those files with the right permissions.